# Replace an OEM recovery partition from Windows Vista, with one from now-upgraded Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, windows-vista

I have a recovery partition from Windows Vista, and I upgraded my laptop to Windows 7. Can I create from Windows 7 a new recovery partition?

Also, would this be legitimate (legal)? The laptop only has a Windows Vista sticker. :/

Comment: The nice little sticker on your laptop is just for decoration. As long as you onw a Windows 7 license, you may install it on any computer you want.

Comment: But install Windows 7 from update is not OEM version connected with computer install on ?

Comment: If you want to use Windows Upgrade, that will not work with most OEM or MSDN licenses. As far as I know, there is no direct upgrade from vista to 7 anyway.

Comment: See this article, you can skip some steps as you already have the needed partition...http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/21978-Windows-7-OEM-Recovery-Partition-tools-creator-Free

Comment: @MichaelK - You cannot use a Windows 7 OEM licence on 'any computer you want.'

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace it, but it does no longer work after upgrade (different MBR, etc) and you can simply delete that partition via Disk Management or diskpart.